# A way to limit the length of varchar greater than 7 and less than 12

Tags: sql

Hey guys is there a way wherein I can limit the varchar of my sql column varchar EmployeeID(12) where Employee ID must be more than 7 and less than 12 in length?
So the table will not allow the user to store record if it did not meet the criteria above
Thank you.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Test
ADD CONSTRAINT checkEmpID CHECK (Employee >=7 AND Employee <=12);
```

And when I try to insert it does not work saying that there is a conflict with check constraints and when i exceed the 12 its truncating

Comment: What is the DBMS where you want to implement this? Please add a tag for the DBMS to your request. You'll want a restriction on the **length** of the employee ID, so you'll have to use `LENGTH` or `LEN` or whatever your DBMS uses to get a string's length.

Comment: Do you mean `CHECK (LENGTH(Employee) BETWEEN 7 AND 12)`? I think your question is not really clear: Do you want to check the length only or should further conditions be applied? Note:  Depending on your RDBMS, you need `LEN` rather than `LENGTH`

Comment: No need to check the upper limit, your column already has a 12 character limit.

Comment: On a side note: "more than 7" would be `> 7` not `>= 7`. Same for "less than 12", which would be `< 12`, not `<= 12`.

Comment: The string gets truncated when you insert a string longer than 12 characters? Which DBMS is this? It should instead raise an error telling you that the string you want to insert into the column is longer than the column data type length allows.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, I'd guess an exception is raised, but OP has no/poor exception handing.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Test
ADD CONSTRAINT checkEmpID CHECK (LEN(EmployeeID) >= 7 AND LEN(EmployeeID) <= 12);
```